# Set paragraph font in python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx

I am using python-docx 0.7.6.

I can't seem to be able to figure out how to set font family and size for a certain paragraph.

There is `.style` property but `style="Times New Roman"` doesn't work.

Can somebody please point me to an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Support for run styles has been added in latest version of python-docx

Answer (score 49):

This is how to set the `Normal` style to font `Arial` and size `10pt`.

```
from docx.shared import Pt

style = document.styles['Normal']
font = style.font
font.name = 'Arial'
font.size = Pt(10)
```

And this is how to apply it to a `paragraph`.

```
paragraph.style = document.styles['Normal']
```

Using the current version of python-docx (0.8.5).

Answer (score 18):

After reading through the [API documentation](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) I was able to figure out how to create my own style and apply it.  You could create a paragraph style object the same way by changing this code to use WD_STYLE_TYPE.PARAGRAPH. Something that took me a minute to figure out was the objects and at what level they are applied so just make sure you understand that clearly. Something I found counter intuitive is that you define the styles properties after its creation.

This is how I created a character level style object.

```
document = Document(path to word document)
```

# Creates a character level style Object ("CommentsStyle") then defines its parameters

```
obj_styles = document.styles
obj_charstyle = obj_styles.add_style('CommentsStyle', WD_STYLE_TYPE.CHARACTER)
obj_font = obj_charstyle.font
obj_font.size = Pt(10)
obj_font.name = 'Times New Roman'
```

This is how I applied the style to a run.

```
paragraph.add_run(any string variable, style = 'CommentsStyle').bold = True
```

Comment: Thanks! This is sorely missing from the official documentation. Other SO answers imply it isn't supported.

Comment: @alex-nies I tried the same, but in your `.add_style()` line I get an error: `NameError: name 'WD_STYLE_TYPE' is not defined` ... any idea of why?

Comment: @abu `from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE`

Answer (score 3):

Use this code it will help u a lot.

```
import docx
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.enum.style import WD_STYLE_TYPE

doc = docx.Document()

parag = doc.add_paragraph("Hello!")

font_styles = doc.styles
font_charstyle = font_styles.add_style('CommentsStyle', WD_STYLE_TYPE.CHARACTER)
font_object = font_charstyle.font
font_object.size = Pt(20)
font_object.name = 'Times New Roman'

parag.add_run("this word document, was created using Times New Roman", style='CommentsStyle').bold = True
parag.add_run("Python", style='CommentsStyle').italic = True
doc.save("test.docx")
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add the relevant information with your code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for python-docx is here:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

The styles that are available in the default template are listed here:
http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/styles.html

In your example above you used a typeface name ("Times New Roman") instead of a style id. If you use "Heading1" for example, that would change the look of the font, among other things, since it's a paragraph style.

At present there is no API for directly applying a typeface name or font size to text in python-docx, although that and more is coming in the next release, probably within a month. In the meantime, you can define styles for the paragraph and character settings you want and apply those styles. Using styles is the recommended way to apply formatting in Word, similar to how CSS is the recommended way to apply formatting to HTML.

Comment: "In the meantime, you can define styles for the paragraph and character settings you want and apply those styles." Any example of tutorial for this? This is possible with the API right?

Comment: Using styles might be recommended way. But lets say I have 10 paragraphs with each some slight style change. It doesn't really make sense creating 10 styles to apply them. In word, you can always select a paragraph and apply some style changes only to that paragraph.

Comment: We are migrating from PHP (PHPDocx) to Python. PHPDocx is way more advanced, hence the expectations.

Comment: "In the meantime, you can define styles for the paragraph and character settings you want and apply those styles." Any example of tutorial for this? This is possible with the API right? "From the documentation doesn't seem like it."

Comment: If you're just changing formatting at the in-line level, like a phrase in a different font or something, you can do that with character styles. Those are applied at the run level. If you really do have that many different paragraph styles I'd be interested to hear more about your use case. It would be unusual in my experience to have ten out of paragraphs each having unique paragraph formatting, but I'm always open to new experiences :)

Comment: Defining styles is not yet possible via the API. It's coming in the next release though, which should be out in a month or so. The way you do it currently is to define those styles in a "template" document and then start with that document, like `document = Document('my-template.docx')`. The documentation has more on that on this page: http://python-docx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/documents.html

Comment: Hi S, in short: users enter some formatted text using TinyMCE which is stored in HTML format. I am writing HTMLToML function. Now since the user can format the text the way they want, I don't have the knowledge of font info beforehand. Hence the problem with styles.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a full example using the latest version of [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) (1.1.0). This allows you to create headings, paragraphs and footer and set fonts and font sizes independently.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

lorem_ipsum = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."""

document = Document()

h1 = document.add_heading("First heading", level=1)
p1 = document.add_paragraph(lorem_ipsum)
h2 = document.add_heading("Second heading", level=1)
p2 = document.add_paragraph(lorem_ipsum)
footer_with_timestamp = document.sections[0].footer
footer_with_timestamp.paragraphs[0].text = lorem_ipsum

# Set font for all paragraphs.
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        run.font.name = "Arial"

# Set font size for headings.
for paragraph in [h1, h2]:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        run.font.size = Pt(14)

# Set font size for paragraphs.
for paragraph in [p1, p2]:
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        run.font.size = Pt(10)

# Set font and font size for footer.
for run in footer_with_timestamp.paragraphs[0].runs:
    run.font.name = "Arial"
    run.font.size = Pt(8)

document.save("demo.docx")
```