# How to change font styles in python docx for a sentence

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

How do we apply a font name, size, etc to add_run() in python docx.
I have tried the following but it doesn’t work.

```
run = Document().add_paragraph().add_run()
font = run.font
font.name = “MS Gothic”
Document().add_paragraph().add_run(“Some random text”)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For per sentence try the below:

```
import docx
document = docx.Document()
run = document.add_paragraph().add_run()
'''Apply style'''
style = document.styles['Normal']
font = style.font
font.name = 'MS Gothic'
font.size = docx.shared.Pt(15)
paragraph = document.add_paragraph('Some text\n')
'''Add another sentence to the paragraph'''
sentence = paragraph.add_run('A new line that should have a different font')
'''Then format the sentence'''
sentence.font.name = 'Arial'
sentence.font.size = docx.shared.Pt(10)
```

Comment: for per character what will be the method?

Comment: @AzamRafique for per character it should be the same, ie. char = paragraph.add_run('A') and then set the format for char

Answer (score 1):

This was answered before and you can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884703/set-paragraph-font-in-python-docx), you have to apply a style. I've tested the below and it seems to work.

```
import docx
document = docx.Document()
run = document.add_paragraph().add_run()
'''Apply style'''
style = document.styles['Normal']
font = style.font
font.name = 'MS Gothic'
font.size = docx.shared.Pt(15)
document.add_paragraph('Some text').add_run()
```

Comment: That's for the whole paragraph. What about a single sentence