# Python DOCX font size Pt() not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx

I am trying to get this document to change the font size but it keeps saying Pt() is not defined.

I have this:

```
import docx

doc = docx.Document(r"C:\Users\jconshick\Desktop\CodeTest\Spellbook.docx")
para = doc.add_paragraph('').add_run("This is a test")
para.font.size = Pt(12)
doc.save(r"C:\Users\jconshick\Desktop\CodeTest\Spellbook.docx")
```

I keep getting that Pt() is not defined though all the documentation shows this is how is should be. Not sure if it matters but I am using Spyder.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
docx.shared.Pt(12)
```

instead of

```
Pt(12)
```

[By this answer from @PieterduToit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753314/how-to-change-font-styles-in-python-docx-for-a-sentence)