# Changing the font size in python docx

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

I am trying to make the "Scout Census" paragraph font size 48 and the "Statistics:" paragraph font size 22. Here is my attempt:

```
Tstyle = doc.styles['Normal']
font=Tstyle.font
font.name = "Nunito Sans"
font.size =Pt(48)
Title = doc.add_paragraph()
Title_format = Title.paragraph_format
Title_format.alignment=1
TRun= Title.add_run("Scout Census")
TRun.bold=True
doc.add_picture('Scouts_Logo_Stack_Black.png', width=Inches(4.0))

Hstyle = doc.styles['Normal']
Headfont=Hstyle.font
Headfont.name = "Nunito Sans"
Headfont.size =Pt(22)
Heading= doc.add_paragraph("Statistics:")
Heading.bold=True
```

When I run this code, both phrases have a font size of 22. Could someone explain to me why? I believe I have defined two different font objects, each with a different font size. So how can one override the other?

Comment: where do you tell the run/paragraph to use the derived /changed fonts? never used docx but I would assume something like `Title.style = TStyle` or `TRun.font = font` or `TRun.style = Tstyle` or ... something of that like is missing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set paragraph font in python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884703/set-paragraph-font-in-python-docx)