# Python - Is there anyway to create a headline for the extracted .DOC file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

Here're my codes:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document
import pandas as pd
import requests

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.``3945.88 Safari/537.37"
url = "https://emetonline.org/events/past-events/"
data = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": user_agent})
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")

document = Document()

events = soup.find_all("div", class_="col-12")
for event in events:
    event_name = event.find("h4")
    try:
        print(event_name.text)
        document.add_paragraph(event_name.text, style='List Bullet')
    except:
        continue
        print(event_name)

document.save('demo.docx')
```

I want a headline for the document as Times New Roman - 14 font size. Is there anyway that I can do that?

Comment: For me, defining own styles or overwriting existing styles was helpful on that point. It was some time of trying, but worked after a while. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29421050/10272417

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
import requests

user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.``3945.88 Safari/537.37"
url = "https://emetonline.org/events/past-events/"
data = requests.get(url, headers={"User-Agent": user_agent})
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "lxml")

document = Document()

heading = document.add_heading().add_run("Past Events")
heading.font.name = "Times New Roman"
heading.font.size = Pt(14)

events = soup.find_all("div", class_="col-12")
for event in events:
    event_name = event.find("h4")
    try:
        print(event_name.text)
        document.add_paragraph(event_name.text, style='List Bullet')
    except:
        continue
        print(event_name)

document.save('demo.docx')
```

I've added the extra import at the top:

```py
from docx.shared import Pt
```

That is so we can set the font size to 14 point.

I've then added this code that makes the headline:

```py
heading = document.add_heading().add_run("Past Events")
heading.font.name = "Times New Roman"
heading.font.size = Pt(14)
```