# editing font type and size in word documents in a folder

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

I work for a company that sends documents to various clients. We receive these from different vendors who format them according to their companies. I have to ensure that they are all the same format before sending them on.

To that end I am trying to create a program that can search for all the word documents in a folder, change the font size to 13 and the font to garamond

With the code below I can get it only to change the font size. Where am I going wrong?

```
import os
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt

def get_paragraph_runs(paragraph):
    return [run for run in paragraph.runs]

def update_font_to_garamond(document):
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        runs = get_paragraph_runs(paragraph)
        for run in runs:
            run.font.name = 'Garamond'
            run.font.size = Pt(13)  

def update_documents_in_folder(folder_path):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".docx"):
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
                document = Document(file_path)
                update_font_to_garamond(document)
                document.save(file_path)
                print(f"Update complete for '{file_path}'.")
```

Comment: See this link for help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27884703/set-paragraph-font-in-python-docx